# How to avoid spurious oscillations 1D FEM Neumann BC

Tags: finite-element

I am trying to solve the Lamm eqn numerically, using 1-D FEM. What I observe is spurious oscillations at one boundary ($r_b$), which quickly leads to unreasonable values over the entire range. I am looking for advice on how to modify the FE formulation to eliminate these oscillations.

The Lamm eqn is
$${\partial C \over \partial t} +  {1\over r}{\partial (r J) \over \partial r}=Q, \ \ r_a\leq r\leq r_b,$$
and
$$J=s \omega^2 r C - D {\partial C \over \partial r}$$
where $s$ is the sedimentation coefficient, $D$ is the diffusion coefficient, and $\omega$ the angular velocity. The boundary
conditions are that the fluxes $J(r_a,t) = J(r_b, t)= 0$. For simple cases, $s$ and $D$ are constants, but they may also be functions of $C$. $Q$ is a "source function", but it is 0 for our case. The initial condition is typically $C$=constant.

The current FEM formulation uses piecewise linear ("hat") functions for discretization in space, and an implicit method to compute $C(t+\Delta t)$ from $C(t)$.

EDIT: Typical values are $r_a$=5.9, $r_b$=7.2, $C_0$=1, $s=4\times 10^{-13}$, $\omega^2=2.7\times 10^7$, $D=3.6\times 10^{-7}$.

At long times, the solution is proportional to $\exp(r^2)$.

Comment: Could you add some typical numerical values for the different parameters? I'm guessing that $D$ is small compared with $s\omega^2$. There are various ways to deal with these oscillations. In 1D, the most basic approaches more or less boil down to making $D$ larger, somewhat arbitrarily, until the oscillations disappear.

Comment: Your equation reminds me of a convection-diffusion equation. If the convection is large w.r.t to diffusion term ($D$ is relatively small), then your solution behaves like a solution of convection equation. The simplest FE methods do not work well for convection equation because for convection-dominated equations monotonicity is essential. Non-monotonic methods produces oscillations, which you might observe. So the suggestion is to try a simple upwind finite difference method, for example.

Comment: I have added typical numerical values (cgs units). For these $s\omega^2=1\times 10^{-5}$, so it is larger than $D$.

Answer (score 3):

The Lamm equation is a specific example of a convection-diffusion PDE. You can find many references on the difficulties
of numerical solution of this equation (e.g. [Leveque](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0898716292)).

Oscillations in the solution near the boundaries, due to characteristics of the numerical method are a common problem. A key parameter in
understanding the likelyhood of oscillations is the mesh Peclet number given by

$$
P = \frac{s\omega^2r\Delta x}{2D}
$$
where $\Delta x$ is the mesh spacing. Oscillations almost always occur when this number is $>1$. For the Lamm equation and the
constants you provided, for a reasonable mesh, this number is $<1$. However, due to the boundary conditions, particularly at the right
end, there is a very steep gradient in the solution. This, along with even the moderate Peclet number is responsible for the oscillations there.

The obvious solution is to refine the mesh to reduce the Peclet number. This can be done non-uniformly so that, for example, the mesh
is much more refined at the right end. Often, this produces a model that too computationally-costly to solve, but that does not appear to be the case here.

Another alternative is to artificially increase the value of $D$. One of the comments suggested to instead use a forward-difference (upwind)
finite difference method. This has the unfortunate side-effect of significantly increasing $D$ so that the solution is very "smeared" compared
with exact. In the finite element method, you can achieve the same effect by slightly increasing $D$ directly.

By doing a simple web search, I was able to find a number of papers related to numerical solution of the Lamm equation for the particular
application you are interested in. Many of them describe the difficulties of using basic FE methods for this problem and propose more
sophisticated alternatives, such a moving-grid methods, to overcome these problems. I think this one, by [Liu and Chen](http://www.math.colostate.edu/~liu/PUB/2009_NMPDE_LiuChen.pdf), does a particularly nice job in this regard.

Finally, using the parameters you provided, I computed the following solution to your equation using $500$ two-node finite elements and
an implicit time integration algorithm. As you can see, for these parameters and this level of mesh refinement, there is no noticeable
oscillation at the right end.
[image]

Comment: Tnx for looking at this. I ran the same FEM solution as you, and I agree there are no oscillations at high $r$, although there is a small oscillation at the very start, $t=0.01$. The problems I'm having trouble with have $D$ dependent on $C$ (increasing $C$ increases $D$). When I do get oscillations, decreasing the mesh spacing, say from 1500 pts to 24000 pts, doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Exactly how does $D$ vary with $C$?

Comment: Roughly speaking, $D=D_0(1+2bC)$, where $b$ is a constant coeff. It's sometimes more complicated.

Comment: I tried this expression for $D$ with $b=.1, b=1, b=10$ but was unable to reproduce the problem you describe. But there is a much broader question that needs to be answered. Finite element solution of the Lamm equation for this particular application seems to be well-studied (e.g. the Liu paper I reference and many papers by Schuck). What is about their proposed approaches that is not applicable for your case?

Comment: We have been using the FE method originally described in their ref [3] for many years (pre Liu and Chen), without much difficulty. Now, in a more complex situation (2 coupled C's), we have oscillations that do not respond to smaller mesh size. I would consider using the L-C method, but it will be a big undertaking to figure out the details from their brief description. Before undertaking that, I'd like some assurance that it would work. On another topic, may I ask, are you using a FE package to do your tests?

Comment: OK, thanks for the additional insights. I don't have a copy of the Claverie paper (ref 3) but my impression is that it is a very basic FE approach with fixed time-step implicit integration in time. I am solving the equation with some software I wrote that is similar to the MATLAB pdepe function. I am using simple two-node elements in space coupled with the Sundials adaptive ODE solver, IDA, in time. Is the value of $b$ you have been using in the expression for $D$ larger than I tried? I don't see how having *more* diffusion could ever be a problem (i.e. lead to oscillations).

Comment: Oscillations are most serious when there are two C's with coupled $b$'s; i e, $D=D_0(1+b\cdot C)$, where b is a row of a 2x2 matrix and C is a 2-vector. Diffusion is in the opposite direction from sedimentation ($s$), so maybe this is behind the oscillations. Often reducing the time step lessens the oscillations. If you'd like copies of Claverie's paper, or the more recent references for our current method, I could send them to you.

Comment: OK, I'm quite interested in this and would like to understand better the idiosyncrasies of solving this numerically. In particular, if I could reproduce the oscillations you see in the two-equation version, I might see some ways
 to prevent them. The Liu, Cao, and Schuck approaches all seem rather unusual to me. I have a gmail mail account and my user name is w.h.greene.